# Saving in NSDocumentDirectory uniquely

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hi Im really having a hard time saving in my `NSDocumentDirectory`.Im using `AGImagePicker`by the way. Yes I was able to save this in `NSDocumentDirectory`. But how to save them uniquely ( in terms of their own then converting their names into `oneSlotImages`) or save them with their unique IDs then load them back. Sorry Im kinda new to this `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` thing., I think that would be my solution to my other problem for not overlaping them when saving. How to save this using their unique ID, or `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [info objectAtIndex:i]);
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
            NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%d.png", i]];


            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];

            //----resize the images
            image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:image toSize:CGSizeMake(256,256*image.size.height/image.size.width)];

            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

Thanks for the help. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL for each image is unique right? So we can make use of this. Convert the URL into MD5 string (which form a unique identifier for each image). And save with that name (like "*MD5string*.png").

Why can't we use this?
Hope this helps you.

For converting to MD5, please create a file named NSString+MD5.h and put the code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>


@interface NSString(MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5;

@end
```

in it.
Then in the NSString+MD5.m,

```
#import "NSString+MD5.h"

@implementation NSString(MD5)

- (NSString*)MD5
{
    const char *ptr = [self UTF8String];

    unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5(ptr, strlen(ptr), md5Buffer);
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) 
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

    return output;
}
@end
```

Import the `NSString+MD5.h` class where ever you want to use the MD5 function with normal `NSString` object.

In you code if you have the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` string, since it is unique for every file you can convert in to MD5 String like

```
NSString *imgURL    = [NSString stringWithString: UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSString *MD5String = [imgURL MD5];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", MD5String]];
```

Use that path to save your image file.

On Loading,

Convert the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` into MD5 and check in the Documents directory for the file

```
// In this the UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is the URL of media file to load
NSString *imgURL    = [NSString stringWithString: UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSString *MD5String = [imgURL MD5];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", MD5String]];
```

Then do the checking with the `fileExistsAtPath` method of NSFileManager and if exists then load the file from the path. Thats it.

**Note**: For this you want to keep the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` of the images you saved in documents directory locally somewhere in your app (In DB or NSUserDefaults) for make use of then at the time of loading.

Comment: You have the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` of the media file you want to load right?

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda new to this thing. So i don't know how tos.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13716/discussion-between-kobe-o4-and-mathew-varghese)

Answer (score 1):

You could always keep a list of used names and do something like this

```
int i = 1;

while([listOfUsedNames containsObject:nextAvailableTile]) {

      nextAvailableTitle = [kDefaultImageName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %d", i];
      i++;
}
```

// found an unused name

Comment: I think this is the same as checking whether a file already existed with that filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableString *imageName = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];

CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if (theUUID) {
    [imageName appendString:NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID))];
            CFRelease(theUUID);
}
[imageName appendString:@".png"];
```